# Xampp error for blocked port

Tags: windows, mysql, xampp

I am unable to start mysql xampp. it is not working . I have attached screenshot. Please provide me solution.it is showing about to port blocked or missing dependencies.

Comment: There is no screenshot.  It would be preferable to see the error as text anyway.

Comment: Your question doesn’t contain the necessary information to answer your question. Please provide an adequate amount of information showing your diagnostic efforts by editing your question